# How to extract Invoke call to a method with a lambda parameter

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, parameters

I am finding myself writing a lot of these to update the UI thread from a BackgroundWorker (_instance being a reference to the Main class):

```
_instance.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    _instance.DgvResults.DataSource = Results;
    _instance.LblStatus.Text = @"Done!";
}));
```

I would like to extract this block to a method so I can call it like this :

```
RunOnUIThread(() => _instance.DgvResults.DataSource = Results);
```

In other words the goal is to be able to pass a lambda containing the instruction I want to run on the UI thread to this method.  I've been able to do this in Java but I'm quite new to C# still and not sure how to tackle this.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So UI thread is continuing updating UI things? Updating something "every frame" that referencing something even haven't been changed would be not so much desireable...

Comment: This background worker is asking very little of the UI thread but my OCD would much rather have these couple of calls be replaced by a one-liner call to a method!

Comment: Execute functions in the BackgroundWorker events which being executed on UI thread `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted`. Alternative approach in case background worker accessing external resources(database, file or web services)  - use asynchronous methods without background worker

Comment: How's `RunOnUIThread(() => _instance.DgvResults.DataSource = Results)` any different from/better than `_instance.Invoke(() => _instance.DgvResults.DataSource = Results)`? They look essentially the same to me. It's only a one-liner if you wrap each statement in the call, which would actually be _worse_ than the conventional approach. If you really don't like calling `Invoke()` explicitly, you should use a different approach where that's not required, such as taking advantage of existing cross-thread mechanisms in `BackgroundWorker` or using WPF (which does a lot of this automatically)

Comment: Good call, i have one-lined the invocations that I could and kept the ones where I need to send multiple instructions at once as-is.  What are you referencing with "existing cross-thread mechanisms in BackgroundWorker"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but I think you can use `event` delegate.

```cs
// In UI-related code
public event Action UpdateUI;
```

And you can add lambdas you want to be called when something has changed.

```cs
// Other codes
_uiCode.UpdateUI += () => _instance.DgvResults.DataSource = Results;

// More other codes
_uiCode.UpdateUI += () => UpdateSomethingTopPanel();
_uiCode.UpdateUI += () => UpdateSomethingBelow();
...
```

And call these functions via one-line code:

```
// If nothing has added to event, invoking would cause nullref, 
// so we have to check null.
UpdateUI?.Invoke();
```

But be careful, adding something to `event` doesn't check duplicate member. You have to call above code only once.

Comment: So if i understand correctly I would have to create a new event Action for each separate call for it to reset every time?

Comment: "Doesn't check duplicate member" means if you add same things twice, it will called twice when you invoke the event, which will result error, or at least damaging performance. If it's different, then you can freely add it, and call *added lambdas* with `Invoke()` at once.